# requests.get().json() не может из строки-словарь сделать словарь в python3.6.1

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, requests

```
import requests
b=requests.get(r"http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1").json()
```

Почему при некоторых случаях(т. к. выдает рандомные шутки) этот код выдает ошибку(возможно из-за кодировок) и как это исправить?

Comment: потому что у вас сервер иногда возвращает некорректный json, а именно некоторые строки содержат неэкранированные кавычки, например `{"key": "строка "с" кавычками"}`. Кавычки внутри строк надо [экранировать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Экранирование_символов), добавляя перед ними обратный слеш (`\`)

Comment: Понятно. Русские символы не переводятся. Не знаете как это исправить

Comment: а, ну ещё строки в json не могут иметь переводы строки, поэтому все переносы строк нужно заменить на `\n`

Comment: да но по сути там и так стоят \n.

Comment: если в коде стоят `\n`, то в json'е получаются переводы строк. Поэтому в коде должны стоять `\\n`, тогда в json'е будут получаться `\n`

Comment: @Gleb в чем смысл вызова json()? `print(requests.get(r"http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1").text)`

Comment: @DmitryErohin в том что text возвращает текст то есть строку. а так как этот запрос возвращает словарь в виде строки, то нам и нужно перевести эту строку в словарь. но jsondecoder не хочет переводить русские буквы(для этого их надо каким то образом закодировать)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

b = requests.get("http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1")
a = b.text[11:][:-1]
```

Comment: Ответ должен содержать не только код, но и пояснения